# How to change VOLUME to COPY in Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

My workflow consists of three stages:

1. development
2. staging
3. production

The docker configuration on all three platforms is almost the same, except 1 difference. On development I mount the project directory via `VOLUME` instead of copying it via `COPY`.

Now I wonder what's better practice?

Create a Dockerfile for each stage like so

```
project/
    .docker
        development
            apache-php
                Dockerfile
                vhosts.conf
            mariadb
                Dockerfile
        staging
            apache-php
                Dockerfile
                vhosts.conf
            mariadb
                Dockerfile
        etc.
```

or somehow conditionaly change `VOLUME` to `COPY`, but I have no idea how this should work.

Answer (score 0):

## Use inheritance

Create a base image that does not cover the `COPY`/`VOLUME` step and then make dev-, test- and production Dockerfiles that base on your base image.

## Example

*Base Dockerfile*

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN echo test >> /important.txt
```

Then build the base image so it may be referenced by the other Dockerfiles: `docker build -t baseimage .`

*Dev Dockerfile*

```
FROM myrepo:baseimage
VOLUME someVolume
```

Build and run.

*Prod Dockerfile*

```
FROM myrepo:baseimage
COPY src dest
```

Build and run.

## Interesting

Volumes will override conatiner files if used like that:

```
docke run -it -v ~/some.txt:/some/container/folder
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this case the base image has to be ready on the system. I don't use the dockers repository. Is there a way to specify a local Dockerfile or a context with FROM?

Comment: As to my knowledge: Yes you have to build it locally once.

Comment: @michaelbahr "Volumes will override container files"--Then I assume that if the base image already includes a copy step, it can be overridden by a volume declared later in the build? For example via a [Docker Compose volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/volumes-volumedriver).